# PHP objects with configurable data interfaces

Tags: php, design-patterns, object-oriented

I have a `User` class which needs to load data from a variety of sources, e.g. the main user database, WordPress user metadata, authorizations from another app, etc. For the sake of organization, I want to separate out those different data loaders into their own classes. Calls to `$user->get_name()` would appropriately delegate down to whatever backend object provides this information.

How might this look in PHP? Is there a name for this pattern? (And hopefully it's not an anti-pattern.)

I can anticipate people suggesting some embedded objects, like `$user->wordpress` as an interface to the WordPress loader. I have an additional complicating factor, that not all users are present in all of our data stores. My loaders are able to identify if they understand and have data for a given username/id, and they're loaded into the `User` object with a priority level. A given identifier may only trigger a subset of data loaders, so `$user->get_name()` essentially is a consistent interface to user data, wherever it's stored.

I'm evaluating my setup in an effort to make things more testable, and I believe this is an appropriate first step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey maybe you could implement a Composite pattern, looking something like:

[image]

The component execute() method could call al its datasources and so on till you reach a basicDatasource witch may have another hireachy, representing each source.

Now back to you needs, the get_name() function could look like:

```
public function get_name()
{
  $datasource = $this->getDataSourcesForName();
  return $datasource->execute();
}
```

Also a strategy patter may apply.

Hope this helps!